# How to determine why an alert dialog was displayed by Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to fix a bug in a Chrome extension. The bug causes a alert dialog to be displayed seemingly at random. There is not one call to alert, confirm, or prompt in the extension source code. How do I find out why the alert dialog is being displayed?

Comment: You can redefine `window.alert` with `(...args) => { debugger; }` and see what happens. In case this is a web page, you may need to do it in [page context](/a/9517879).

Comment: I do not know what this means:  with (...args). Can you give the actual valid JavaScript syntax since I know "window.alert with (...args) => { debugger; }" is not valid JavaScript syntax?

Comment: It is already JS syntax but split in two to make a coherent English sentence. Replace `with` with `=`.

Comment: @wOxxOm Isn't there a function missing in there somewhere? Another source said to use the following.

window.alert = function() {
    debugger;
}

There is no function in yours.

Comment: I've used *arrow function syntax*.